# return only a single property "_id"

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know if there is a way to return only the `_id`, `user_id` and `total` without the `items` subdocument.

```
{
    "_id" : 122,
    "user_id" : 123456,
    "total" : 100,
    "items" : [
            {
                    "item_name" : "my_item_one",
                    "price" : 20
            },
            {
                    "item_name" : "my_item_two",
                    "price" : 50
            },
            {
                    "item_name" : "my_item_three",
                    "price" : 30
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The second parameter of [find lets you select fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection).  So you can use this (note that the _id field is always selected anyway):

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {"user_id": 1, "total": 1});
```

You can also exclude certain fields, so this would be equivalent:

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {"items": 0});
```

You can exclude _id field by doing:

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {"user_id": 1, "_id": 0});
```

Answer (score 28):

What I was looking for is returning a list of ids, so return only _id but as an array for all documents. I did it as such:

```
db. mycollection.distinct("_id", {})
```

The first parameter is your distict fields, and second is your query. More on distinct [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/). Hopefully this helps someone with a similar requirement. Cheers!

Comment: My googling led me to this SO question and this was the answer I was looking for- though I think the accepted answer is correct for the question. Just endorsing this answer! Thanks @radtek!

Comment: thank you very much...exactly what i searched