# mongodb find and return id as a string - java

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

Morning,

Seem to be having a brainfart! Have had a look around and can't see any one else having the same issue so I've either completely missed something (most likely) or nobody else has this use case.

I basically want to return all objects stored in a mongodb collection, including their id's, however as the string representation rather than the full object. So this:

```
public ArrayList findAllObjects(){
      return db.getCollection("objects").find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
}
```

```js
{
  _id: {
    class: "org.bson.types.ObjectId",
    counter: 7230903,
    date: "2016-10-03T12:39:38Z",
    machineIdentifier: 5652488,
    processIdentifier: 8859,
    time: 1475498378000,
    timeSecond: 1475498378,
    timestamp: 1475498378
  },
  name: "Test Object"
},
```

Now if I run a find on the mongo console I get something along the lines of:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57f2518a564008229b6e55b7"),
  "name": "Test Object"
}
```

It's this 57f2518a564008229b6e55b7 that I'd like to return in the original json as the _id (potentially could add under another name) field.

I can get that string representation in the java code simply by running get getObjectId() on an individual document. So I could possibly loop through every result and set/add the _id but that feels like a bit of a smell to me.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Update:

Thanks Sinclair for the comments, I don't believe this is a duplicate though, as I do actually want to include the id not necessarily exclude anything. If the string representation was in the org.bson.types.ObjectId object as a property I could then potentially exclude the rest but that isn't the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return only a single property "\_id"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026476/return-only-a-single-property-id)

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only

Comment: Can yo use this syntax in Java? db.mycollection.find({}, {"user_id": 1, "total": 1});

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to string simply using the toString() method:

```html
List<Document> documents = collection.find().into(new ArrayList<>());

documents.parallelStream().forEach(document -> {
     document.put("_id", document.get("_id").toString());
});
```