# Faster way to store data from MongoDB into array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Does anybody know faster way to store data from mongodb Collections into js arrays?
Cause code below is way too slow. Maybe using aggregation? Or something else?
I need only ids from the collection docs.

```
payments = await db.collection("accounting-payment").find({}).toArray()
```

Comment: Does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11026476/3083470) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `filter` at the query level and `index` at db collection level.

1. Filter will reduce data import by applying filter, unless you do not need all the data.
2. If you do need all the data, you can use `cursor` which will work like pagination.
3. Also, you can create `index` at db collection level, which will speed up data fetching only if you are applying query and not fetching almost all the records.
   If you are fetching all/almost all the records, then index will slow the performance because of lookup+fetch double operation.
4. Also you can use query projection like `.find({}, {name:1,desc:1})` which will only return the fields which has been set to 1. This will reduce data fetch volume over the wire.